# Android Disable autocomplete for android:inputType="number"

Tags: android

Does `android:inputType="number"` enables autocomplete  in any case (certain keyboard types)?
What's the way to explicitly disable autocomplete for number fields? The problem with `number|textNosuggestions` is, it doesn't give a pure numeric keypad.